# Frechet Derivatives of normed spaces

Tags: derivatives, normed-spaces

[image]

(a) Would I use the definition of an open set for one U? How do I show the function is Frechet differentiable. I know the definition but not sure how to apply it.

$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\lVert f(x+h)-f(x)-A_xh\rVert}{\lVert h\rVert}=0\quad$

(b) The notation is confusing me. Do I just sub the functions into the definition?

(c) Again not entirely sure. I get $d(f+g)(x) = d((\sigma\ (f\times g)\ \alpha)(x)) = d((\sigma\ (f\times g)) (x,x)) = d((\sigma\ (f(x),g(x))) =  d((f(x)+g(x))$.

Comment: Use the definition of the norm to show that $U \times U$ is open. The differentiability of $f \times g$ follows using this norm and the fact that $f,g$ are differentiable. I don't know what you are asking in (b). (c) follows from the fact that $f+g = \sigma\circ (f\times g)\circ \alpha$. You can show this by just expanding $\sigma, \alpha$.

Comment: to show the function is Frechet differentiable at $(u,v)$ you can write its frechet derivative at $(u,v)$ and show it is a bounded linear operator (easy as the norm is simply the sum $||.||_X+||.||_Y$)

Comment: Is my part (c) correct?

Comment: @copper.hat How would I use the definition to show $U \times U$ is open?

Comment: I added an answer to (a) below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(a) Suppose $U$ is open. Pick a point  $(x,y) \in U \times U$. Since $U$ is open,
there is some $\epsilon>0$ such that $B(x,\epsilon) \subset U$, $B(y, \epsilon) \subset U$.

Then if $\|(x,y)-(x',y')\| = \|x-x'\|+\|y-y'\| < \epsilon$, we must have
$\|x-x'\| < \epsilon$ and $\|y-y'\| < \epsilon$, that is,
$B((x,y), \epsilon) \subset B(x,\epsilon) \times B(y, \epsilon) \subset U \times U$. Hence $U \times U$ is open.

To compute the derivative of $\phi((u,v)) =(f(u),g(v))$, first guess what it should look like. If you 'perturb' $(u,v)$ to get $(u+h_1,v+h_2)$ then you
expect $f(u+h_1) \approx f(u)+A_1 h_1$, $g(v+h_2) \approx g(v)+A_2 h_2$,
where $A_1,A_2$ are the derivatives of $f,g$ respectively.
Hence you expect that
$\phi((u+h_1,v+h_2)) \approx (f(u)+A_1 h_1,g(v)+A_2 h_2) = \phi((u,v)) + (A_1 h_1, A_2 h_2)$. So, we expect the derivative of $\phi$ to be the linear map
$(h_1,h_2) \mapsto (A_1 h_1, A_2 h_2)$. (It is easy to check that this map is
continuous, since $A_1,A_2$ are.

Now we verify this guess.
\begin{eqnarray}
{\| \phi((u+h_1,v+h_2)) - \phi((u,v)) - (A_1 h_1, A_2 h_2) \| \over \|(h_1,h_2) \| } &=& {\| f(u+h_1) - f(u) - A_1 h_1 \| + \| g(v+h_2) - g(v) - A_2 h_2 \|\over \|(h_1,h_2) \| }
\end{eqnarray}
Now note that $\lim_{\|(h_1,h_2) \| \to 0} {\| f(u+h_1) - f(u) - A_1 h_1 \| \over \|(h_1,h_2) \| } = 0$ and similarly for the $g$ part. Hence
$\lim_{\|(h_1,h_2) \| \to 0} {\| \phi((u+h_1,v+h_2)) - \phi((u,v)) - (A_1 h_1, A_2 h_2) \| \over \|(h_1,h_2) \| }  = 0$, and so $\phi$ is 
differentiable with derivative $(h_1,h_2) \mapsto (A_1 h_1, A_2 h_2)$.

Here is the derivative of $\alpha$: First a guess, note that
$\alpha(x+h) = (x+h,x+h) = \alpha(x) + (h,h)$, and since the function 
$h \mapsto (h,h)$ is linear we guess that $D\alpha(x)h = (h,h)$. It is
immediate to check that this is the derivative using the definition (the
quotient is always zero).

Here is the derivative of $\sigma$:  As above, a guess first.
Note that $\sigma(y+h,y'+h') = \sigma(y,y') + h+h'$ so we guess that
$D \sigma((y,y')) ((h,h')) = h+h'$. Again, it is easy to verify using the definition.

In general, if $A$ is a continuous linear operator, we have
$A(x+h) = Ax + Ah$, so we can quickly check that $D A(x)h = Ah$, that is,
it is its own derivative.

To finish, **carefully** apply the chain rule.

If $\phi = f \circ g$ then $D \phi(x)h = Df(g(x))Dg(x)h$.

---

If $F(x) = f(x)+g(x)$, then as above we guess first, then verify: 
$F(x+h) = f(x+h)+g(x+h) \approx f(x)+A_1h + g(x)+A_2h = F(x) + (A_1+A_2)h$,
so we guess that the derivative is $h \mapsto (A_1+A_2)h$. That is,
you have $DF(x)h = (Df(x)+Dg(x))h$ or more simply, $DF(x) = Df(x)+Dg(x)$.

---

\begin{eqnarray}
D (\sigma \circ (f \times g) \circ \alpha) (x) h &=& D \sigma(((f \times g) \circ \alpha)(x)) D ((f \times g) \circ \alpha)(x)h \\
&=& D \sigma((f(x),g(x))) D ((f \times g) \circ \alpha)(x)h \\
&=& D \sigma((f(x),g(x))) D (f \times g)(\alpha(x)) D \alpha(x)h \\
&=& D \sigma((f(x),g(x))) D (f \times g)(\alpha(x)) \alpha(x)h \\
&=& D \sigma((f(x),g(x))) D (f \times g)(\alpha(x)) (h,h) \\
&=& D \sigma((f(x),g(x))) D (f \times g)((x,x)) (h,h) \\
&=& D \sigma((f(x),g(x))) (Df(x)h, Dg(x)h) \\
&=& \sigma((Df(x)h, Dg(x)h)) \\
&=& Df(x)h +Dg(x)h \\
&=& (Df(x) +Dg(x))h \\
\end{eqnarray}
Since this is true for all $h$ we see that 
$ D (\sigma \circ (f \times g) \circ \alpha) (x) = Df(x) +Dg(x)$.

Comment: Does the Frechet differentiability at (x,x) follow because f and g are frechet differentiable at x?

Comment: Yes,  much like in the finite dimensional case.

Comment: How would I set it out using the norms?

Comment: Just write the definition with the product norm, expand it in terms of the definition of the product norm and do a little estimation. You need to just try it.

Comment: Thanks I have got it. What about the Frechet derivative? I'm not sure what A is

Comment: It is really no different than the finite dimensional case. What would you expect the derivative of a function of the form $(x,y) \mapsto (f(x),g(y))$ to be? It may help to expand the function to first order and guess, that is replace $f(x+h)$ by $f(x)+f'(x)h$ and similarly for $g$ and remember that $x,y$ are different variables and that there will be two $h$', one for the $x$ variable and on for the $y$ variable.

Comment: Thanks and is my part (c) correct?

Comment: Well, you haven't used the chain rule. You need to compute the derivative of $\alpha$ and $\sigma$. See above for the derivatives.

Comment: For (a) $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{\|(f(x+h)-f(x),g(x+h)-g(x))-Ah\|}{\|h\|} = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{\| \|(f(x+h)-f(x)\|+\|g(x+h)-g(x))\|-Ah\|}{\|h\|}$ What is Ah?

Comment: You need to write $Ah = (A_1 h, A_2h)$ and the $A_1h$ goes with the $f$ part, and similarly for $A_2h$. You should be able to guess where the $A_1,A_2$ come from (hint: $f,g$ are differentiable).

Comment: So $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{\| \|f(x+h)-f(x)-A_1h\|+\|g(x+h)-g(x)-A_2h\|\|}{\|h\|}$ and then the sum of differentiable functions is differentiable? Do I have to replace $A_1h$ and $A_2h$ with identity?

Comment: You should write $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{ \|f(x+h)-f(x)-A_1h\|+\|g(x+h)-g(x)-A_2h\|}{\|h\|} = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0}  ( \frac{ \|f(x+h)-f(x)-A_1h\|}{\|h\|} + \frac{\|g(x+h)-g(x)-A_2h\|}{\|h\|})$. From this you should know where $A_1,A_2$ come from, remember that $f,g$ are differentiable. Look at the definition in Part (a).

Comment: Ah yes then it follows from the fact that f and g are differentiable at $x$.

Comment: For the Frechet derivative do I replace $(x,x)$ with $(u,v)$ and do the same thing? Or is it asking for the derivative at $(x,x)$?

Comment: I don't understand your last question. You need to develop some intuition. The derivative is a continuous linear function $A$ (usually denoted $f'(x)$ or $Df(x)$)  such that $f(x+h) \approx f(x)+f'(x)h$, where the approximation is given by the limit. But the idea is that you are using a linearised approximation of the function locally.

Comment: So, if a function is already a continuous linear one, then it is its own derivative. This gets the derivatives of $\sigma, \alpha$ easily. It follows because $L(x+h)-Lx -Lh = 0$ for a linear function.

Comment: Don't get lost in the symbols, think of what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am still confused about $A_1h$ and $A_2h$. For the first part do I just say since f and g are differentiable, their sum is differentiable or do I have to replace $A_1h$ and $A_2h$ with something. If you have any particular examples which are explained in books/sites please let me know.

Comment: I will add something to my 'answer' above.

Comment: Is the Frechet derivative $dF(x)= df(x)+dg(x)$ where $F=f+g$?

Comment: So the derivative of $\alpha$ is $(1,1)$ or $(id,id)$?

Comment: So the point of Frechet derivatives is guessing A so that the limit=0?

Comment: The derivative is a linear map, and for linear (continuous) functions, they are their own derivatives, so $D \alpha(x) h = \alpha(h) = (h,h)$. That is, the map $h \mapsto (h,h)$. You could write it as $\text{id} \times \text{id}$.

Comment: I have been told $df(x)=A$ (note no h). So for (b) it would be $id \times id$ and $1+\frac{h'}{h}$?

Comment: Well, the point of the derivative is to have a useful local approximation to $f$, and the derivative is that local approximation. One technique for computing the derivative, as with many aspect of mathematics, is to guess & verify. In many practical cases, the form can be guessed by replacing $x$ by $x+h$, or $f(x+h)$ by $f(x)+f'(x)h$.

Comment: $Df(x)$ is a linear map, so has the form $h \mapsto Df(x)h$. For (b), as I mentioned above, both $\sigma$ and $\alpha$ are linear (and continuous) so they are their own derivatives. That is, $D\sigma(x) = \sigma$ and $D\alpha(x) = \alpha$.

Comment: So writing $(h,h)$ and $h+h'$ is fine? Or should I write $\alpha$ and $\sigma$

Comment: What is d(x,x)? Is it $(1,1)$? and what is d(f(x),f(x))? is it (df(x),df(x))

Comment: Well, I would write either $\alpha$ or $h \mapsto (h,h)$ for the first and $\sigma$ or $(h,h') \mapsto (h+h')$ for the second.

Comment: Technically the derivative is a continuous liner map. So $D\alpha(x)$ is a map $h \mapsto (h,h)$. If you are looking at $\alpha:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ you could represent $D \alpha(x)$ by a matrix $(1,1)^T$, if that is what you are asking.

Comment: No, the point of (c) is for you to apply the chain rule to $\sigma \circ (f \times g) \circ \alpha$ and show that $D (\sigma \circ (f \times g) \circ \alpha) (x) h = Df(x)h+Dg(x)h$.

Comment: Can I split it up? By letting $a=(f \times g) \circ \alpha$?

Comment: You can do it whatever way you want. The chain rule gives $D (\sigma \circ (f \times g) \circ \alpha) (x) h = D \sigma(((f \times g) \circ \alpha)(x)) D ((f \times g) \circ \alpha)(x)h$. You need to expand it one more time. It is a mess of symbols, but straightforward.

Comment: Yes I can see the mess of symbols. I have $d(f(x)+g(x)) \circ d(f(x,x),g(x,x)) \circ d(x,x)$

Comment: That is not correct, you really need to be careful with parentheses. The notation for the derivative of $f$ at the point $x$ evaluated in the direction $h$ is $Df(x)h$.  I will add an answer later (hours), I need to so a lot of other stuff now.

Comment: I added an answer for (c) to the end. I have made one change at each step in the derivation, so it should be straightforward to follow. While it may not be clear to you at this stage, later you might note that by including the $h$ in the derivation makes some steps more straightforward.

Comment: For part (a) Do I need to use $h=(h_1,h_2)$ or is $(h,h)$ fine? This is to show function is Frechet differneitable at $(x,x)$

Comment: For Part (a) you **must** use $(h_1,h_2)$ since you are dealing with a function $(u,v) \mapsto (f(u),g(v))$.

Comment: Thanks in the comments I used $(h,h)$ and you continued with it. But thanks for the clarification now.

Comment: For Part (a) I can't see where I used $(h,h)$, can you tell me where it is because it should be fixed.

Comment: It is in the comments (about 12th comment)

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake, but don't want to disturb the flow of comments. Look at the answer where is says 'To compute the derivative...', that is the correct derivation.

Comment: Yes thanks again